# html <pre></pre> page layout blocks links

Tags: c#, html, .net, hyperlink

I am taking a document into an html page to show the user with .Net libraries' help. I am using LoadHtml method under HtmlAgilityPack. But when i use that method to fill the html, it does not show the tab(ascii=09) characters right. So i use it like:

```
doc.LoadHtml("<pre>" + pContent + "</pre>");
```

But when i do that then i can not add any picture links or pictures to the html page. normally before i use "< pre >", the user was able to add links. The code below was running behind.

```
string text = string.Format(@"<img src='{0}' />", thepicturelink);
```

My problem is that i want to make my page both could be added links(pictures) and looks proper with tab character. I could not find any solution for that in here, msdn, socialmsdn, codeproject or google. Does anyone have a solution for that problem? Thank for helps. Best regards.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your problem with the TABs? Could you provide a picture showing the problem or more code?

Comment: it is looking like the text file "AddictiveTips Data" in the link when i use tab chars and <pre>, and without is down picture.   http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/import-text-file-in-access-2010/

Comment: Is `pContent` a variable that just contains the contents of the text file? The whole page? What do you do after you load the HTML? Do you process it somehow and then return the newly generated HTML? Do you simply return the contents as they come? Where is the code that controls the action of adding a link by a user? How does it work? When you ask something, try to provide as much information as possible. Help us be able to help you...